# Saltstack - need to get some info from a minion scheduled event

Tags: saltstack

I've got a minion scheduled event (/etc/salt/minion.d/_schedule.conf) which runs a particular state file using the `state.sls` function. I've got jid_include and return_job set to "true". I know the event runs based on the effect the state file has on our host, but I'd like to get more details about it each time it runs. Basically I'd like it to run the equivalent of `salt-call -l debug state.sls` and have it put that debug output somewhere. It doesn't seem to be doing this by default, as I cannot find any information about this scheduled event in the master or minion log files. Any idea where to find more info about this job?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that one cannot pass `-l debug` to the state.sls function. However, one can set `cache_jobs: True` in /etc/salt/minion and this has the effect of putting the results of the jobs into /var/cache/salt/minion/minion_jobs. The results of the scheduled jobs then can be examined with `salt-call saltutil.find_cached_job /var/cache/salt/minion/minion_jobs/req`.